# Raphael.js onmouseover onmouseout event

Tags: raphael, mouseevent, onmouseover, onmouseout

I've made 4 rectangles in raphael.js using the **for loop**. When I apply events such as onmouseover or onmouseout it applies only to the last rectangle created. I know something is wrong in my code. Please provide a solution and is there a way to simplify the code?

JS Fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/TL78u/3/)

```
window.onload = function(){
    var paper = Raphael(0,0,640,540);

    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
        for (j=0;j<2;j++){
            var boxes = paper.rect(0+(j*320),0+(i*270),320,270).attr({fill:'#303030',stroke:'white'});
            boxes.node.onmouseover = function () {
                boxes.attr("fill", "blue");
            };
            boxes.node.onmouseout = function () {
                boxes.attr("fill", "#303030");
            };
        }
    }    
}​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extremely common mistake in javascript. You reuse the `boxes` variable, so when any of the handlers are executed, it points to the last value it had.

The common way of overcoming this is to wrap the code inside the loop in a function call:

```
window.onload = function() {
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 640, 540);

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        (function(i, j) {
            var boxes = paper.rect(0 + (j * 320), 0 + (i * 270), 320, 270).attr({
                fill: '#303030',
                stroke: 'white'
            });
            boxes.node.onmouseover = function() {
                boxes.attr("fill", "blue");
            };
            boxes.node.onmouseout = function() {
                boxes.attr("fill", "#303030");
            };
        })(i, j);
    }
}
}
```

​